# Is there an R funtion to return a value if a word from my list matches a word in a string

Tags: r

Is there a R function to check whether a word from my list is present in a string and if yes return another value?

```
Address
10 Sydney, South East
11 Mumbai, North West
12 London, Central Town
```

.

```
City  Country
Mumbai India
Sydney Australia
London Britain
```

Output:

```
Address                   Country
10 Sydney, South East     Australia
11 Mumbai, North West     India
12 London, Central Town   Britain
```

Sample code -

```
influencer %>%
    mutate(AC.Name = AC_Village$AC.Name[match(AC_Village$Town, 
           str_extract(Complete.Address,paste(AC_Village$Town, collapse="|")))])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! your question has not a reproducible code and data, could you add them? It seems a kind of join that you're asking, but if so, I do not understand the question.

Comment: I have kept address as one data frame and city/country as another data frame

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to extract the 'City' of 'Address' column from the 'City' column of second dataset, do a `match` and get the corresponding 'Country'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Country = df2$Country[match(df2$City, str_extract(Address, 
          paste(df2$City, collapse="|")))])
#                   Address  Country
#1   10 Sydney, South East Australia
#2   11 Mumbai, North West     India
#3 12 London, Central Town   Britain
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Address = c("10 Sydney, South East", "11 Mumbai, North West", 
"12 London, Central Town")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(City = c("Mumbai", "Sydney", "London"), Country = c("India", 
"Australia", "Britain")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: I am getting this error after executing - Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)

Comment: @MichaelDreamworks  Is this based on the `data` copy/pasted from my post or in your original data.  I checked by running the code again.  It is working fine for me

Comment: It is based on my original data @akrun.. any idea why is the error coming?

Comment: @MichaelDreamworks Not clear about the error.  If you can update your post with a small example (`dput` output) that gives the error, would be useful

Comment: @MichaelDreamworks  code wouldn't help if you have used the same code as in my post